# Looking for generic xslt which extracts the elements and values from the xml string

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Looking for XSLT

Sample Incoming xml with xml string inside  -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <app4:App > <app4:appId>45645dfg</app4:appId> <app4:appType>Insert/Update</app4:appType> <app4:appName>Optin</app4:appName> <app4:source>Store</app4:source> <app4:target>apm</app4:target> <app4:corelationId>564654456</app4:corelationId> <app4:payload> <ns0:xmlString>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt; &lt;app6:consumers xmlns:app6="http://www.example.org/consumer_Notification" xmlns:ns="http://com.equinix.product/consumerxa"&gt; &lt;app6:consumerId&gt;yjtuj&lt;/app6:consumerId&gt; &lt;app6:consumerNumber&gt;gdfhfh&lt;/app6:consumerNumber&gt; &lt;app6:orderNumber&gt;657467476&lt;/app6:orderNumber&gt; &lt;app6:accountNumber&gt;75654757&lt;/app6:accountNumber&gt; &lt;app6:accountUcid&gt;6574575747-15C8E09FBEBD&lt;/app6:accountUcid&gt; &lt;app6:productName&gt;updateportal&lt;/app6:productName&gt; &lt;app6:metro&gt;MB&lt;/app6:metro&gt; &lt;app6:country&gt;Japan&lt;/app6:country&gt; &lt;app6:consumerType&gt;Patch Panel&lt;/app6:consumerType&gt; &lt;app6:consumerPartNumber&gt;654757.COMP&lt;/app6:consumerPartNumber&gt; &lt;app6:Status&gt;Active&lt;/app6:Status&gt; &lt;/app6:consumers&gt;</ns0:xmlString> </app4:payload> </app4:App>
```

Looking for Output xml - with well parsed xmlstring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <app4:App > <app4:appId>45645dfg</app4:appId> <app4:appType>Insert/Update</app4:appType> <app4:appName>Optin</app4:appName> <app4:source>Store</app4:source> <app4:target>apm</app4:target> <app4:corelationId>564654456</app4:corelationId> <app4:payload> <ns0:xmlString><app6:consumers xmlns:app6="http://www.example.org/consumer_Notification" xmlns:ns="http://com.equinix.product/consumerxa"> <app6:consumerId>yjtuj</app6:consumerId> <app6:consumerNumber>gdfhfh</app6:consumerNumber> <app6:orderNumber>657467476</app6:orderNumber> <app6:accountNumber>75654757</app6:accountNumber> <app6:accountUcid>6574575747-15C8E09FBEBD</app6:accountUcid> <app6:productName>updateportal</app6:productName> <app6:metro>MB</app6:metro> <app6:country>Japan</app6:country> <app6:consumerType>Patch Panel</app6:consumerType> <app6:consumerPartNumber>654757.COMP</app6:consumerPartNumber> <app6:Status>Active</app6:Status> </app6:consumers></ns0:xmlString> </app4:payload> </app4:App>
```

Comment: The input you show is not well-formed XML. In general, you can use `<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="some-node"/>` to unescape a string. However, you will need to remove the XML declaration first.

Comment: Upstream process is sending this way and they cannot modify their code This need to be handled in XSLT –

Comment: The input you show cannot be handled in XSLT because it is not a well-formed XML document.

Comment: XSLT 3 has the `parse-xml` function for that, Saxon versions since 9.8 support that, as Altova XML since 2017 R3. Older XSLT 2 processors might provide an extension function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input has namespaces declared for `app4` and `ns0` then with XSLT 3 you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*:xmlString">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml(.)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```